# implementing operator precedence in arithmetic operation

Tags: javascript

I have a code but it is not working for operator precedence. It is normally executing from first to last operator entered in a string.
It gives correct answer while string follow precedence rule`(eg."12 * 10 / 5 + 10 - 1"  = 33 <- correct answer)`. But it gives wrong answer while string doesn't follow precedence rule`(eg. "15 + 10 * 5 / 10 - 1" = 49 <- wrong answer. actual answer is 19)`

code:

```
var str="12 * 10 / 5 + 10 - 1";
var res=[],n1=[],num=[],op=[],o1=[];
var result;

res= str.split(" ");
console.error("res",res);
document.write(res.join(",")+"<br>");

for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
  {
  num.push(parseInt(res[i]));
  }
  else
  {
  op.push(res[i]);
  } 
}
document.write(num+"<br>");
document.write(op+"<br>");

var myFunction = function(num1,num2,oper){

    var j;
    if(oper=='-'){
      j = num1-num2;
      return j;
    }else if(oper=='+'){
      j = num1+num2;
      return j;
    }else if(oper=='*'){
      j = num1*num2;
      return j;
    }else if(oper=='/'){
      j = num1/num2;
      return j;
    }else{
      j = 0;
      return j;
      } 
    }
 var x=num[0];
 for(var i=1; i<num.length; i++){
    x = myFunction(x,num[i],op[i-1]);
  }

 document.write("result of "+str+" is "+x+"<br>");
```

Comment: It seems to be a shift/reduce problem. In math expression (and not only) you can't be sure you can reduce expression (solve a part of if), only if you know the next operator has lower priority than actual operator. If it does not happen, you must keep checking for operators (shift). You can also choose for a recursive solution, in which you start "breaking" your math expression in lower priority operators (+, -), in order to keep this operations in the function stack base, to be solved at last.

Comment: This probably would be better with a recursive solution. Without actually trying to solve it, I would suggest you need to scan the list of operators for `*/`, then process the numbers relevant to that operator first, generating new number/operator sets, then continuing until you have just the result. This becomes more complex if you then want to start handling brackets though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser

Comment: Yes, it's not working like that. What did you try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. I like because this is how we craft a parser. There are other approaches as mentioned, usual when you're using a parser generator like lex/yacc.

As you have noticed, there are times we need to save an intermediate result in order to process another part of an expression. This way, called a recursive descent parser, uses the environment's own stack to save the temp results. Another way is to use maintain a stack yourself, but that's not much valuable.

This is also very flexible. It's pretty easy to extend the grammar to different precedence levels. Change `parseFactor` below to parse negation and parentheses.

```js
function parse(expression) {
  return expression.split(' ')
}

function consumeNumber(tokens) {
  const token = tokens.shift()
  return parseInt(token)
}

function consumeOp(tokens, allowed) {
  const token = tokens[0]
  if (allowed.indexOf(token) >= 0) {
    tokens.shift()
    return token
  }
}

function parseFactor(tokens) {
  return consumeNumber(tokens)
}

function parseTerm(tokens) {
  let value = parseFactor(tokens)
  let op
  while (op = consumeOp(tokens, ['*', '/'])) {
    let nextVal = parseFactor(tokens)
    switch (op) {
      case '*': 
        value *= nextVal
        break
      case '/': 
        value /= nextVal
        break
    }
  }
  return value
}

function parseExpression(tokens) {
  let value = parseTerm(tokens)
  let op
  while (op = consumeOp(tokens, ['+', '-'])) {
    let nextVal = parseTerm(tokens)
    switch (op) {
      case '+': 
        value += nextVal
        break
      case '-': 
        value -= nextVal
        break
    }
  }
  return value
}

function evaluate(expression) {
  const tokens = parse(expression)

  return parseExpression(tokens)
}

evaluate('15 + 10 * 5 / 10 - 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacked together (read: shouldn't actually be used anywhere real without extra work / error checking) object which gets the correct answer for both test cases. I'm sure this could be improved on and there's likely better algorithms for this. As per my comment it just scans for `*` or `/` and processes that calculation, then generates a new number/operator set including that result. I mainly just wrote it for fun.

I haven't bothered with the code to try and parse the string, this just takes an array of numbers and an array of operators.

(Also I get `11.5` as the incorrect result for your second test, both manually and running your code)

```
<script>
myCalc = {

  getResult: function(n, o){

    this.numbers = n;
    this.operators = o;

    // keep going until our list of numbers is just the final result
    while( this.numbers.length > 1 )
      this.findNext();

    return this.numbers[0];
  },

  findNext: function(){

    var opIndex = 0;

    // find the next * or / operator
    for(i=0;i<=this.operators.length;i++){

      if( this.operators[i] == '*' || this.operators[i] == '/' ){

        opIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    var opResult = this.doCalc(this.operators[opIndex], this.numbers[opIndex], this.numbers[opIndex+1]);

    // update our main numbers list and splice out the operator we just processed
    // replace "x" with the result, and splice "y"
    this.numbers[opIndex] = opResult;
    this.numbers.splice(opIndex + 1, 1);
    this.operators.splice(opIndex, 1);

    console.log(this.numbers);
    console.log(this.operators);
  },

  doCalc: function(op,x,y){

    switch(op){
      case '*':
        return x * y;
      case '/':
        return x / y;
      case '+':
        return x + y;
      case '-':
        return x - y;
    }

    return 0;
  }
};

console.log(myCalc.getResult([15,10,5,10,1], ['+','*','/','-']));
console.log(myCalc.getResult([12,10,5,10,1], ['*','/','+','-']));
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Since nobody mentioned it before, you could simply process your string with [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function:

```
var str="15 + 10 * 5 / 10 - 1";
console.log(eval(str));
// logs 19
```

> If the argument is an expression, eval() evaluates the expression

Comment: I know this sounds like cheating: if this is some homework  probably the teacher wouldn't be very happy about it. But in the real world, you should never [reinvent the wheel](http://deviq.com/reinventing-the-wheel/)

Comment: Yee my first downvote without explanation!!! (finally I'm a real SO user..)

Comment: this could have been just a comment

Comment: @AndréWerlang In which way exactly this is not an answer to the presented problem? Since this is a programmer Q&A, if I have a working solution to a problem, I post it as an answer.... But thanks for the explanation, at least!

Comment: imo it wasn't an answer in the spirit of the question. that's not me the downvoter btw, find another to blame

Comment: well, decided to downvote as well. you made me think about it, and `eval` is exposing the complete environment to the expression. so, not an answer, right?

Comment: At least you tried to explain your dw, but how "exposing the complete environment to the expression" make this not an answer? Please be more specific if you can!

Comment: it does more than requested, and it should be mentioned but wasn't. Even then, OP mentioned a pretty finite vocabulary (numbers, *, /, +, -) but suddenly it would be able to take a much larger one.

Comment: Hmmm, the OP didn't say that the vocabulary should be limited (indeed someone in the comment mentioned parenthesis)... Anyway the input string can be easily filtered if we want to allow only certain values, but that's definitely not part of the question.